# Array Addition in java?

Tags: java, arrays, addition, variance

I have so far a program that asks the user to choose a number of elements. The program then asks the user to choose numbers as many times indicated by the number of elements. How would I find the variance of this set of numbers using only arrays and either while or for loops. Nothing too fancy as I am in high school. Below is my current code:

```
//write an app that finds the variance of a set of numbers
class temp1 {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    int counter = 0;
    String question;
    question = "How many elements do you want?: ";
    EasyReader console = new EasyReader();
    System.out.println(question);
    int answer;
    int answer2;
    answer = console.readInt();
    int[] numbers = new int[answer];
    int mean;
    System.out.println();
    while(true)
    {
    System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
    answer2 = console.readInt();
    counter++;
    if(counter==answer)
    {
    break;
    }
    }
    mean = (numbers[0]+numbers[1]+numbers[2]+numbers[answer])/answer;
    System.out.print(mean);
    }
    }
```

Comment: You use the loops to iterate over the elements and calculate it. Check your notes on how to use loops and how to calculate variance, then use Java to program it.

Comment: I know how to find the variance, it's just I don't understand arrays. I'm not sure how to add the contents of the array. Would I use a loop for that?

Comment: Go through [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: You are welcome. A suggestion, Stackoverflow doesn't like code requests. When asking for code, we want you to include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't realize. Should I post my current code and etc in the description?

Comment: You should post the relevant parts of it, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program may be like:

//write an app that finds the variance of a set of numbers

```
class temp1
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int counter = 0;
        String question;
        question = "How many elements do you want?: ";
        EasyReader console = new EasyReader();
        System.out.println(question);
        int answer;
        int answer2;
        answer = console.readInt();
        int[] numbers = new int[answer];
        int mean;
        System.out.println();
        while (true)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
            answer2 = console.readInt();
            numbers[counter] = answer2;
            counter++;
            if (counter == answer)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        counter = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        while(true)
        {
            sum = sum + numbers[counter];
            counter++;
            if(counter == answer)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        mean = sum / answer;
        System.out.print(mean);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is the Scanner command the same as the EasyReader one?

Comment: I dont know any EasyReader, Scanner is supplied by Java, EasyReader class may be given to you by your tutor.